# My partial is not where rails expects it to be (nested partials)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

I have a model Submissions which has many Performers. I have a partial for showing an individual submissions (app/views/submissions/_submission.html.erb):

```
<div>
  Show stuff relating to @submission
  ...
  <%= render @performers %>
</div>
```

and a partial for showing performers (app/views/performers/_performer.html.erb):

```
<%= div_for performer do %>
  <%= performer.name %>
<% end %>
```

This works fine from (app/views/submissions/show.html.erb):

```
<%= render @submission %>
```

But I want to use this from a different namespace too (app/views/curator/submissions/show.html.erb). But I get this error:

```
Missing partial curator/submissions/submission with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/ircmullaney/RubyCode/cif/app/views"
  * "/Users/ircmullaney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
```

I can fix this by changing the render to this:

```
<%= render 'submissions/submission' %>
```

But, then the nested partial fails:

```
Missing partial curator/performers/performer with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/ircmullaney/RubyCode/cif/app/views"
  * "/Users/ircmullaney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
```

This doesn't work:

```
<%= render 'performers/performer' %>
```

because of the div_for:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Any ideas how I should do this?

UPDATE: In addition to the change that iouri suggested, I added this to my performer partial:

```
<% @performers.each do |performer| %>
  <%= div_for performer do %>
    <%= performer.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move them into a separate folder under views, called partials for examples, then reference them from there in both places, you will need to pass your object to the partial:

```
<%= render 'partials/performer', :locals => {:performer => @performer} %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't think that solves the undefined 'model_name' issue.

Comment: try passing an abject to the partial

Comment: That worked, but I also needed to add an each block in the performer partial. I'll update above. Thanks!